# DNN 6.02.08 Upgrade to 7.02.02 FromsAuthentication module Error

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, upgrade

I have to upgrade may DNN 6.02.08 environment to the 7.02.02.

I have follow the upgrade process carefully and the upgrade is successful, but I am facing this error : Module not found : 
'Boolean System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.get_IsEnabled()'

I have upgrade from DNN 6.02.07 to DNN 6.02.08 without errors, and I use the suggested upgrade path found on that link : 
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/suggested_upgrade_path

What can I do to resolve this issue ? is this a major change between DNN 6.x to DNN 7.x FormsAuthentication function ?

I really don’t found a response on the web and forums so thanks for help.

Comment: I would start by checking to see if you have .NET 4.5 installed on the web server.

Comment: Thanks for the responce, i am using the .NET 4. And DNN 7 is compatible ! http://www.dnnsoftware.com/platform/start/install

Comment: So I would try installing .net 4.5 on the server and see if that fixes your issue, someone might have slipped in a requirement for 4.5 into the 7.2.2 release unintentionally

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I am using DNN on a windows server 2008 standard SP1 version. The .NET 4.5 framework is not available on that version. I have try to upgrade to the DNN 7.0.0 version and the upgrade is successful with any exception ! but when i try with older versions i got the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Okay, so that pretty much rules out your ability to upgrade to DNN 7.2.2

Comment: Hi, for infos now i don't have the exception anymore, I use the .NET framework 4 and I have upgraded the MS server 2008 to SP2 version. Maybe that was the source of the issue. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problems I encounter when upgrade from early versions of DNN (5 or 6) to a latter version of DNN7 usually are solved my comparing and merging web.config changes after the upgrade is finished.

Here is one interesting and VERY annoying problem.  In some version of DNN 7.1 or 7.2 or something, DNN changed the assembly that houses the SQlDataProvider.  So in a DNN 6 web.config you will see the following line:

```
<add name="SqlDataProvider" 
     type="DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke.SqlDataProvider" ... />
```

But in the DNN 7.3.4 web.config, the line looks like this:

```
<add name="SqlDataProvider" 
     type="DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke" ... />
```

Notice the assembly changed from DotNetNuke.SqlDataProvider to the core DotNetNuke assembly.  There are other examples of these types of changes that get missed in the upgrade events sometimes.  Just use a text compare tool on your web.config with the one from the latest DNN install package and merge these discrepancies.